# Deployment blocked

Tags: html, css, ftp, sftp, ovh

I am in local and set up a gitlab pipepline to deploy my feature in our web site.

When I push my files in ftp client (FilleZilla) I can see the same folder and files and the  modication date.

But I when refresh our distant site I can't see any modifcations thant I have done in local.

Have someone met this issue or give me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the cache in your server if you have any ?
or delete ur client cache